# Math constants generalization

Tags: constants

Does any generalization for "famous" math constants (like $\pi$ or $e$) exist.

I know how those constants are useful, but I do not know what property makes them useful.

Is there any definition of those numbers which can include some additional numbers. (Those additional number can be part any super-set of $R$ or $C$).

What property of those constants is making them "special"?

Comment: $\pi$ and $e$ are irrational, so a little bit special.

Comment: just google the definitions of $e$ and $\pi$

Comment: $3$ is a famous constant. What makes it special?

Comment: @Kirill "irrationality" is rather common ($\sqrt{2}$ is irrational) and does not distinguish them from the "vulgus pecus"; **transcendentality** is much less common...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by generalizing a constant.  They are fixed and so how could you generalize them?

Comment: They are like the Kardashians. They are useful precisely because they are famous.

Comment: @Kirill I was googling and I did not found answer to my question.

Comment: @Qudit I cannot exactly answer to your question, because it is a part of my question. In mathematics we are doing all kinds of generalization. Like extending $sin$ function from right triangle to unit circle definition. Addition of complex number is some kind of generalization of  addition of real numbers.
So with every "generalization" we are somehow extending a scope. So are those "special" number part of some bigger set of numbers which all share same characteristic as those numbers.

Comment: @JeanMarie Might depend on what you mean by "common".  In the sense of measure theory, almost every real number is transcendental.  In the sense of Baire category, a generic real number is transcendental.  On the other hand, being **proved** transcendental is somewhat special.

Comment: so, @Vasoli, what are possible definitions of $e$ and $\pi$?

Comment: @Vasoli As other have mentioned, they are irrational and transcendental.  I don't think much more can be said beyond that in terms generalizing them.

Comment: @Qudit There might be some generalization of $\pi$ and some other generalization of $e$. I do not expect to have same generalization of both of those numbers. We can generalize that 1 and 0  as neutral elements in $(R, *, +)$ field. So we can observe other neutral elements, and neutral elements are some kind of generalization of 0 and 1. Maybe there is some generalization of  $\pi$ and $e$. I do not know, that is why I am asking.

Comment: @Robert Israel You are right: It is "proved transcendentality" which isn't common.

Comment: Relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/341470/is-there-any-deep-philosophy-or-intuition-behind-the-similarity-between-pi-4

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you may be interested in [ring of periods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods), recently developed by Kontsevich and Zagier, generalizing the constants you mentioned. More details in the Wikipedia article and its references. According to Kontsevich and Zagier, "all classical constants are periods in the appropriate sense".

Comment: I voted up your answer (Also Adams). I will keep question open. Maybe we get some additional interesting answer.

Comment: How many periods are there? One reason the transcendental numbers do not seem like a good generalization is because almost every real number is transcendental.

Comment: I have not read much about "periods" but they seem more like algebraic numbers which are countable.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for non-algebraic ( transcendental ) numbers? Certainly, something shared with pi and e.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicNumber.html

Comment: That might be one answer. But I do not see that  transcendental have that much in common with those 2 except being transcendental. I will leave question unanswered because maybe someone have some better answer then that, if that answer exist.

Answer (score -1):

Well, we can calculate $\pi$ by 
$$\pi = \lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2} * n * \sin{(\frac{n}{360})}$$
And $e$ by using
$$e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{n!})$$
Those two definitions are somewhat the proof that they can't actually be calculated. However, since they do occure in nature, they are very speciall.
Also, the beautiful equation
$$e^{i * \pi} + 1 = 0$$
States that they are relative to each other and $\sqrt{-1}$ (an imaginary number), which, once again, makes both of these very special.

Comment: This celebrated relationship should not be interpreted as meaning a special link between $e$ and $\pi$ ! You could find other constants with other "close relationships".

Comment: I knew all of this, but this does not answer my question. This is not "generalizing" them in any way. I not saying that there is a generalization, I am asking if there is one.

Comment: You question was "what property of these two constants is making them special?" Which is that they both can be defined by either using $\infty$ or each other and $i$, and they still are to be found in nature. That's what makes these two special. Either this or redefine the last line of the question.

Comment: And if you want to know what makes them useful: $\pi$ is used to calculate circle-related equations, and $e$ is used to calculate air pressure by height, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You can probably say the same thing for 2 and 3 and they are not "special".  That they can be calculated in terms of each other and i.

I know how they can be used, how they can be calculated and lots of their "fine" properties. What I do not know is how I can distinguish them from other numbers. With precise mathematical definition. I have that property for 1 and 0. They are neutral elements. But I do not see such a property with pi, e or i.

Comment: Ach so, well $e$ and $/pi$ also are irrational (unable to write it in a fraction) unlike 2 and 3. Also, 2 and 3 don't have a non-recursive relation to $\infty$, which $e$ and $\pi$ do

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie I like your "Ach so", somewhat not translatable in English...